# Closed community wikis lost RSS feeds?

Tags: support, closed-questions, community-wiki, feed

I noticed that questions and community wikis have RSS feeds, but if a community wiki is [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90924/what-is-the-best-php-programming-book) it don't have RSS feed.

For example, [this](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/3593/what-are-famous-quotes-about-productivity) community wiki is open and users can benefit from subscribing to its RSS channel.

Why is this so? Will it be changed or is there a reason for this?

Comment: Is there any point having an RSS feed for a question which will never get any new answers?

Comment: @JamesAllardice It's community wiki not a question and wiki's should be opened for new editions I think. It's the sense of wikis.

Comment: But it's closed. It cannot get any new responses. If there was an RSS feed, what would be the point of subscribing to it? I assume that if it is reopened, the feed will be regenerated.

Comment: The question is if it's right for community wiki to be closed. I think, that community wiki should automatically reopen, otherwise it contradicts the purpose of wiki. Question should be closed but not wikis.